# How can BigQuery show anomalies in log data?

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

I need to know if there is an easy way to have BigQuery 'bubble up' log entries that fall outside of the norm without setting static thresholds. To be specific, I intend to put log data (e.g. people with RFID tags moving around a building), and over time a regular pattern would emerge, for example, people arriving at the office every weekday and leaving late afternoon.

I need to see the exceptions on any such repeated pattern, for example, new RFID tags being seen for the 1st few days (while a pattern is not yet established) and regular tags being seen over weekends, as an example. Would an 'exception query' be possible and do you have a guide/examples of how to do this with log data being streamed into BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't offer a **built-in** way to accomplish this, but if you can express your anomaly detection algorithm in SQL (or as a Javascript UDF), it seems reasonable enough.

A search turned up one example that might be a useful starting point:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/nikhilk/demo-logs-analysis/blob/master/notebooks/RequestLogs.ipynb

In general, I'd approach this in two parts:

- Write a query to generate your model from existing data.
- Run a query that compares new entries against your model, classifying them as "expected" or "anomalous".

Even if it is impractical to train your model directly in SQL, comparing new entries **against** the model is likely to be much easier to express.